# WCF service authenticated outside network

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, authentication, iis

I have a WCF Service posted to IIS so that it can be accessed publicly with the right credentials.  For the past few days I have been trying to get the service to work outside of my company's network.  But nothing I do has worked.

Inside my company network, I can call the service and work with it without issues.  I can locate the service externally through the browser.  When I try to use the service in code outside the network, I get error messages:
`The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'.`

That error was after I reordered the authentication providers to Ntlm and then Negotiate.

What am I missing so that clients outside the company network can access the service?

App.Config of Test in Console Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpEndpoint">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://<iis server>/services/360Review/ReviewSvc.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpEndpoint"
            contract="WebSTGReviewReference.IReviewSvc" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Test Program in Console Application

```
enter code here
EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://<BizTalk server>/<service folder>/ReviewSvc.svc");
BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

try
{
    ServiceReference.ReviewSvcClient client = new ServiceReference.ReviewSvcClient(binding, endpoint);
    ServiceReference.ActivityType act = client.GetActivityTypes()[0];
    Console.WriteLine("Test 1 Complete");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    if (e.InnerException != null)
        Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
}
```

Web.Config of WCF Service on IIS

```
<configuration>

<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://<BizTalk Server>/<service folder>/ReviewSvc.svc"
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IReviewSvc"
    contract="BTReviewSvc.IReviewSvc" name="BasicHttpsBinding_IReviewSvc" />
  </client>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="BasicBinding">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="SSLBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" />
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IReviewSvc">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="<namespace>.ReviewSvcBehavior" name="<namespace>.ReviewSvc">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SSLBinding" name="BasicHttpEndpoint" contract="<namespace>.IReviewSvc"></endpoint>
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
       <behavior name="<namespace>.ReviewSvcBehavior">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping>    
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
    -->
  <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: It looks like your using active directory authentication inside your network and of course the clients outside the network are not domain members so NTLM won't work there. See: [Securing Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734769.aspx) for more information on how to secure WCF services.

Comment: how does the web.config file for the service look like?

Comment: perhaps this could help you out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36289/steps-to-enable-windows-authentication-on-WCF-Ba

Comment: @Jocke See update section Web.Config of WCF Service on IIS

Comment: Is NTLM added as a provider for IIS: http://debugmode.net/2009/12/18/ntlm-and-windows-authentication-on-wcf-service/

Comment: @Jocke, I used that tutorial initially when setting up the service.  But it is only for internal since it uses Windows authentication which wont work outside the network so far as I am aware.

Comment: @Jocke, Yes.  Ntlm is set up as a provider for IIS.  It is currently set as the priority Provider before Negotiate.